# Double Quotes appearing in a String within Select SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

I have asked a few of my colleagues about removing double quotes, but to no avail we are having no luck.  If I just put 'Q3', '2013' and 'B50931' in the actual SQL Select Query below, this code works flawlessly. As soon as I try to pass the form fields via a string, double quotes appear and I get a Run-Time Error '3061': Too Few parameters. Expected 3.
On the first strQtr, I tried this:

```
 strQtr = Mid([Qtr_ADD], 2, Len([Qtr_ADD]) - 2)
```

This nets me strQtr = ""
The others net me strYear = "2013" and strGL_BU = "B50931"

Maybe I am way off base, but these need to be 'Q3', '2013' and 'B50931' in order to run the select query.
Once again, any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
 Private Const cSQLConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;Etc    
 Private Sub Image96_Click()

 Dim dbs As DAO.Recordset
 Dim strRecSetSubQuery, strRecSetMaster As String
  Set DB = CurrentDb

 strQtr = Mid([Qtr_ADD], 2, Len([Qtr_ADD]) - 2)
 strYear = [Year_ADD]
 strGL_BU = [BU_Selected_Add]

 strRecSetQuery = ""
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "SELECT  "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "       [QTR] , "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "       [Year] , "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "       [GL_BU]  "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "FROM   dbo_tTbl_Admin_RxRebate"
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + " WHERE  ( [QTR] = strQtr ) "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "       AND ( [Year] = strYear ) "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "       AND ( [GL_BU] = StrGL_BU ) "


  Debug.Print strRecSetQuery
    Set dbs = DB.OpenRecordset(strRecSetQuery, dbOpenDynaset)
     If dbs.RecordCount = 1 Then
     MsgBox "This Business Unit already exists within the database." & Chr(13)      & "Please make sure to enter a Non-DS related Business" & Chr(13) & "Unit and resubmit?",      vbExclamation, "Business Unit Check"
   Else
     End If
 'dbs.Close
 'Set dbs = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the format you want for your SQL - assuming Quarter, year and GL_BU are all strings, otherwise remove the single quotes:  It produces the following:

```
SELECT  [QTR], [Year], [GL_BU]  
FROM dbo_tTbl_Admin_RxRebate 
WHERE ([QTR] = 'Q3') AND ([Year] = '2013') AND ([GL_BU] = 'B50931') 


 strRecSetQuery = ""
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "SELECT  "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "[QTR], "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "[Year], "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "[GL_BU]  "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "FROM dbo_tTbl_Admin_RxRebate"
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery & " WHERE ([QTR] = '" & strQtr & "') "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "AND ([Year] = '" & strYear & "') "
 strRecSetQuery = strRecSetQuery + "AND ([GL_BU] = '" & strGL_BU & "');"
```